# On the use of the function principal() in R

Tags: r, principal

I'm using the function principal() from the psych package. 
My code is as follows:

```
fit <- principal(stdmat, covar = FALSE, nfactors = 14, rotate = 'varimax')
```

I just had some questions about the output. First, when checking the loadings, they were given in a random order, e.g. PC1 PC2 PC8 PC4 etc, which I find a bit odd. So, just wondering is PC3 still referring to the third principal component and not the order of how they are given (in the order given in the example, then PC8 would then refer to the third principal component)?

Second, I was wondering why I did not get RCi instead of PCi in my output, because I used a rotation, and I read in the information of the function that it makes the distinction between the rotated and unrotated components. But I just get PCi's, or is there another function you need to use to get the rotated components, and not just `fit$loadings`?

Thank you in advance.